# Wso2 Data Service Not Running

Tags: ubuntu, wso2-data-services-server

Im new to linux. I want to run wso2 data service in Ubuntu but im having trouble. When i try to run wso2server.sh, it says wso2server.sh command not found, did i do wrong? I can't start wso2. What is the best way to run it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Start the server with "sh wso2server.sh" in bin directory

Comment: it Helps! @Jenananthan